# In Bootstrap, how do I make my stepper full width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```css
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.col {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://uselooper.com/assets/vendor/fontawesome/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://uselooper.com/assets/stylesheets/custom.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://uselooper.com/assets/vendor/open-iconic/css/open-iconic-bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://uselooper.com/assets/stylesheets/theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- .card -->
<div class="card">
  <!-- .card-body -->
  <div class="card-body">
    <!-- .progress-list -->
    <ol class="progress-list mb-0 mb-sm-4">
      <li class="success">
        <button type="button">
        <!-- progress indicator -->
        <span class="progress-indicator"></span></button> <span class="progress-label d-none d-sm-inline-block">Step 1</span>
      </li>
      <li class="success">
        <button type="button">
        <!-- progress indicator -->
        <span class="progress-indicator"></span></button> <span class="progress-label d-none d-sm-inline-block">Step 2</span>
      </li>
      <li class="active error">
        <button type="button">
        <!-- progress indicator -->
     <span class="progress-indicator"></span></button> <span class="progress-label d-none d-sm-inline-block">Step 3</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <button type="button">
        <!-- progress indicator -->
        <span class="progress-indicator"></span></button> <span class="progress-label d-none d-sm-inline-block">Step 4</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <button type="button">
         <!-- progress indicator -->
         <span class="progress-indicator"></span></button> <span class="progress-label d-none d-sm-inline-block">Step 5</span>
      </li>
    </ol>
    <!-- /.progress-list -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.card-body -->
  <!-- .card-body -->
  <div class="card-body">
    <p> Earum temporibus consequuntur facilis iste obcaecati soluta, inventore, vero labore accusantium in commodi eaque, similique necessitatibus ab dolorem non repudiandae pariatur culpa! </p>
  </div>
  <!-- /.card-body -->
</div>
<!-- /.card -->
```

I have the following fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/47cpaor3/1/

I would like the stepper to be be full width.

I have tried changing:

`<ol class="progress-list mb-0 mb-sm-4">`

to

`<ol class="progress-list mb-0 mb-sm-4" style="width: 100%">`

but this does not work.

How do I stretch the stepper to full width?

Comment: The stepper _**IS full width**_.  What you are seeing is that each item in the stepper is of equal width, and the content is centered, which means that each item in the stepper has extra space on the left / right.  That space on the first / last items are creating the illusion it's not full width.  This fiddle, where I've added border, demonstrates this fact: https://jsfiddle.net/cj56szo2/

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```css
    .progress-list>li {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: left;
    }
    .progress-list>li:before {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 10%;
        margin-top: -1px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 3px;
        background-color: rgba(34,34,48,.1);
    }
    .progress-list .progress-label {
        display: inline-block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 1.75rem;
        left: 16%;
        transform: translate3d(-50%,0,0);
        font-size: .875rem;
        color: #888c9b;
    }
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not useful, further, if this is in bootstrap, it'd be ideal to use _bootstrap_ to fix it, not add a bunch of additional CSS...

Answer (score 0):

I put some borders on so we see stuff and set padding on `progress-card` to 0 but unclear what other changes you might desire.

```css
.card {
  border: solid blue 1px;
}

.card .card-body.progress-card {
  border: solid red 1px;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}

.card .progress-list {
  border: 1px solid lime;
}

.card .progress-list .success,
.card .progress-list .error,
.card .progress-list>li {
  border: 1px solid pink;
}


/*
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.col {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
}
*/
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://uselooper.com/assets/vendor/fontawesome/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://uselooper.com/assets/stylesheets/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://uselooper.com/assets/vendor/open-iconic/css/open-iconic-bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://uselooper.com/assets/stylesheets/theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body progress-card">
    <ol class="progress-list">
      <li class="success">
        <button type="button"><span class="progress-indicator"></span></button>
        <span class="progress-label d-none d-sm-inline-block">Step 1</span>
      </li>
      <li class="success">
        <button type="button"><span class="progress-indicator"></span></button>
        <span class="progress-label d-none d-sm-inline-block">Step 2</span>
      </li>
      <li class="active error">
        <button type="button"><span class="progress-indicator"></span></button>
        <span class="progress-label d-none d-sm-inline-block">Step 3</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <button type="button"><span class="progress-indicator"></span></button>
        <span class="progress-label d-none d-sm-inline-block">Step 4</span>
      </li>
      <li class="">
        <button type="button"><span class="progress-indicator"></span></button>
        <span class="progress-label d-none d-sm-inline-block">Step 5</span>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <p> Earum temporibus consequuntur facilis iste obcaecati soluta, inventore, vero labore accusantium in commodi eaque, similique necessitatibus ab dolorem non repudiandae pariatur culpa! </p>
  </div>
</div>
```